# reactor-logback configuration with groovy

Tags: groovy, logback

I use logback 1.1.2 with groovy configuration.
I want to use reactor-logback, but I can't configure with appenderRef.
Logback's AsyncAppender allows 'appenderRef' but, reacter-logback does not.

How can I configure reactor-logback with groovy configuration?

```
appender('stdout', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = '%-5level %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %logger{36}.%method - %msg%n'
    }
}

appender('reactorStdout', reactor.logback.AsyncAppender) {
    appenderRef('stdout')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use this with stable logback-classic yet.
You'll have to use snapshot of the logback-classic:1.1.3 until it is released.
Here's the snippet from my `build.gradle`

```
compile("io.projectreactor:reactor-logback:$reactorVersion") {
    exclude module: 'logback-classic'
    exclude module: 'logback-core'
}
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
```

I couldn't find the snapshot in repositories, so I built it myself and installed to mavenLocal() repository. This is very strightforward:

```
git clone git@github.com:qos-ch/logback.git && cd logback
mvn install
```

Comment: Ha, funny situation :) Well, I guess having an answer for this question for others is still good. As for your work - thank you, when I noticed your fix it made my day :)